# Can't access external Hive metastore with Pyspark

Tags: hive, pyspark, metastore, hive-metastore

I am trying to run a simple code to simply show databases that I created previously on my hive2-server. **(note in this example there are both, examples in python and scala both with the same results).**

If I log in into a hive shell and list my databases I see a total of **3 databases**.

When I start Spark shell(2.3) on pyspark I do the usual and add the following property to my SparkSession:

```
sqlContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://*****:9083")
```

And re-start a SparkContext within my session.

If I run the following line to see all the configs:

```
pyspark.conf.SparkConf().getAll()
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

I can indeed see the parameter has been added, I start a new HiveContext:

```
hiveContext = pyspark.sql.HiveContext(sc)
```

But If I list my databases:

```
hiveContext.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()
```

It will not show the same results from the hive shell.

I'm a bit lost, for some reason it looks like it is ignoring the config parameter as I am sure the one I'm using it's my metastore as the address I get from running:

```
hive -e "SET" | grep metastore.uris
```

Is the same address also if I run:

```
ses2 = spark.builder.master("local").appName("Hive_Test").config('hive.metastore.uris','thrift://******:9083').getOrCreate()
ses2.sql("SET").show()
```

Could it be a permission issue? Like some tables are not set to be seen outside the hive shell/user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue, because a communication issue the Hive was not hosted in that machine, corrected the code and everything fine.